# Invalid MIT magic cookie when connecting to X server

Tags: sockets, x11

I'm trying to write my own code to connect to an X server. I ran xauth to get the magic cookie I needed and wrote the following code to try and test out establishing a connection:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{  
  int sockfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

  struct sockaddr_un serv_addr;
  memset((void*)&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
  serv_addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
  strcpy(serv_addr.sun_path, "/tmp/.X11-unix/X0");
  int servlen = 17 + sizeof(serv_addr.sun_family);

  int err = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, servlen);

  char arr[] = {108, 0, // 'l' for little-endian
                11, 0, // X version
                0, 0,  // X minor version
                18, 0, // length of auth protocol name
                16, 0, // length of auth protocol data
                0, 0, // padding
                77, 73, 84, 45, 77, 65, 71, 73, 67, 45, 67, 79, 79, 75, 73, 69, 45, 49, // MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1
                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                223, 88, 218, 121, 215, 6, 185, 105, 137, 80, 105, 252, 49, 109, 38,  200, // data from .Xauthority
                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

  ssize_t bytes_written = write(sockfd, arr, sizeof(arr));
  printf("%d\n", bytes_written);

  uint8_t buf[5000];
  ssize_t bytes_read = read(sockfd, buf, 5000);
  printf("%d\n", bytes_read);

  unsigned char k;
  for(k = 0; k < 40; k++) {
    printf("%c", buf[k]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The X server responds all right but it gives me an authentication failed message with "Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key" as the reason. The key I'm giving is the same as the one in my .Xauthority file (df58da79d706b969895069fc316d26c8, in case anyone wants to check!) Is there something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have too much of padding zeroes. should be:

```
  char arr[] = {108, 0, // 'l' for little-endian
                11, 0, // X version
                0, 0,  // X minor version
                18, 0, // length of auth protocol name
                16, 0, // length of auth protocol data
                0, 0, // padding
                77, 73, 84, 45, 77, 65, 71, 73, 67, 45, 67, 79, 79, 75, 73, 69, 45, 49, // MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1
                0, 0, // two bytes to pad 18-byte MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 to factor of 4 - 20
                223, 88, 218, 121, 215, 6, 185, 105, 137, 80, 105, 252, 49, 109, 38,  200 // data from .Xauthority
                }; // no need for more padding, auth data is 16 bytes long, factor of 4
```

From page 140 of [X11 protocol](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/xproto/x11protocol.pdf):

```
Information sent by the client at connection setup:

1 byte-order
 ▶x42 MSB first
 ▶x6C LSB first
 1 unused
 2 CARD16 protocol-major-version
 2 CARD16 protocol-minor-version
 2 n length of authorization-protocol-name
 2 d length of authorization-protocol-data
 2 unused
 n STRING8 authorization-protocol-name
 p unused, p=pad(n)
 d STRING8 authorization-protocol-data
 q unused, q=pad(d)
```